# SikuliX scripts cannot find the button to click only at VMWare (Windows Server 2016)

Tags: windows, sikuli-x

I have a strange issue which only occurred at `Windows Server 2016 VMWare`.
I have to set the VMWare Display at guest OS do not use host resolution, and set specific resolution 1920x1200 with Text scale at 100%.

Otherwise the action to click on button does not proceed.

The same script is used at VMWare Windows 10 without problem. I can set VM to use host resolution, auto scale.

Any idea what is the cause?

Tentatively I have used the workaround mentioned at above, however I want to permanent fix.
Because the view of VM is pretty awful, small screen and text.

[image]